# Spring Batch return is not working so logs and another code does not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch

I was working Spring Batch for inactive accounts. But the return type doesn't work. In `inactiveMemberProcessor` `log.info("InactiveMemberProcessor execution")` doesn't work.

Not only the log but also the code cannot be executed because the return is not possible.

Why does this happen?

```
package com.capston.chatting.config.batch;

import com.capston.chatting.entity.Member;
import com.capston.chatting.enums.MemberStatus;
import com.capston.chatting.repository.MemberRepository;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemProcessor;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.support.ListItemReader;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.List;

@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Configuration
public class InactiveMemberJobConfig {

    private final MemberRepository memberRepository;
    private final JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
    private final StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Bean
    public Job inactiveMemberJob() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("inactiveMemberJob3")
                .start(inactiveJobStep())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step inactiveJobStep() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("inactiveMemberStep")
                .<Member, Member>chunk(10)
                .reader(inactiveMemberReader())
                .processor(this.inactiveMemberProcessor())
                .writer(this.inactiveMemberWriter())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ListItemReader<Member> inactiveMemberReader() {
        log.info("InactiveMemberReader execution");
        List<Member> oldMembers = memberRepository
                .findByUpdateDateBeforeAndStatusEquals(LocalDateTime.now().minusYears(1), MemberStatus.ACTIVE);
        for (Member oldMember : oldMembers) {
            log.info("oldMembers = {}", oldMember.getName());
        }
        return new ListItemReader<>(oldMembers);
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemProcessor<Member, Member> inactiveMemberProcessor() {
        log.info("test");
        return new ItemProcessor<Member, Member>() {
            @Override
            public Member process(Member member) throws Exception {
                log.info("InactiveMemberProcessor execution");
                return member.setInactive();
            }
        };
//        return member -> {
//            log.info("InactiveMemberProcessor execution");
//            return member.setInactive();
//        };
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<Member> inactiveMemberWriter() {
        log.info("InactiveMemberWriter execution");
        return ((List<? extends Member> members) -> {
            memberRepository.saveAll(members);
            log.info("Members : {}", members);
        });
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.7.2)

2022-08-21 20:31:27.400  INFO 10044 --- [  restartedMain] c.capston.chatting.ChattingApplication   : Starting ChattingApplication using Java 11.0.12 on DESKTOP-SHB62PK with PID 10044 (D:\chatting\chatting\build\classes\java\main started by user in D:\chatting\chatting)
2022-08-21 20:31:27.401  INFO 10044 --- [  restartedMain] c.capston.chatting.ChattingApplication   : The following 4 profiles are active: "google", "naver", "kakao", "local"
2022-08-21 20:31:27.423  INFO 10044 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2022-08-21 20:31:27.423  INFO 10044 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2022-08-21 20:31:27.799  INFO 10044 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-08-21 20:31:27.832  INFO 10044 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 29 ms. Found 4 JPA repository interfaces.
2022-08-21 20:31:28.160  INFO 10044 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2022-08-21 20:31:28.165  INFO 10044 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-08-21 20:31:28.165  INFO 10044 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.65]
2022-08-21 20:31:28.239  INFO 10044 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-08-21 20:31:28.239  INFO 10044 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 816 ms
2022-08-21 20:31:28.287  INFO 10044 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2022-08-21 20:31:28.445  INFO 10044 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2022-08-21 20:31:28.507  INFO 10044 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2022-08-21 20:31:28.529  INFO 10044 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.10.Final
2022-08-21 20:31:28.597  INFO 10044 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2022-08-21 20:31:28.649  INFO 10044 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
2022-08-21 20:31:28.900  INFO 10044 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2022-08-21 20:31:28.904  INFO 10044 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-08-21 20:31:29.331  INFO 10044 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@e2a9a2e, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@8f52ad, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@5d28bf88, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@682aa17e, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@4b700064, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@5266a5db, org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter@5f76bf5b, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@4a39d06c, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@6cc78b9b, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@4bed4ca2, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@34652a4a, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@33fe6437, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@5e47964]
2022-08-21 20:31:29.338  INFO 10044 --- [  restartedMain] c.c.c.c.batch.InactiveMemberJobConfig    : InactiveMemberReader execution
2022-08-21 20:31:29.355 DEBUG 10044 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
    select
        member0_.member_id as member_i1_3_,
        member0_.created_date as created_2_3_,
        member0_.login_id as login_id3_3_,
        member0_.login_pw as login_pw4_3_,
        member0_.name as name5_3_,
        member0_.role as role6_3_,
        member0_.score as score7_3_,
        member0_.status as status8_3_,
        member0_.update_date as update_d9_3_ 
    from
        member member0_ 
    where
        member0_.update_date<? 
        and member0_.status=?
2022-08-21 20:31:29.397  INFO 10044 --- [  restartedMain] c.c.c.c.batch.InactiveMemberJobConfig    : oldMembers = resultMember
2022-08-21 20:31:29.398  INFO 10044 --- [  restartedMain] c.c.c.c.batch.InactiveMemberJobConfig    : test
2022-08-21 20:31:29.399  INFO 10044 --- [  restartedMain] c.c.c.c.batch.InactiveMemberJobConfig    : InactiveMemberWriter execution
2022-08-21 20:31:29.518  WARN 10044 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.batch.JpaBatchConfigurer         : JPA does not support custom isolation levels, so locks may not be taken when launching Jobs. To silence this warning, set 'spring.batch.jdbc.isolation-level-for-create' to 'default'.
2022-08-21 20:31:29.520  INFO 10044 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.c.r.s.JobRepositoryFactoryBean     : No database type set, using meta data indicating: MYSQL
2022-08-21 20:31:29.529  INFO 10044 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : No TaskExecutor has been set, defaulting to synchronous executor.
2022-08-21 20:31:29.608  INFO 10044 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2022-08-21 20:31:29.628  INFO 10044 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2022-08-21 20:31:29.629  INFO 10044 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.m.s.b.SimpleBrokerMessageHandler     : Starting...
2022-08-21 20:31:29.630  INFO 10044 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.m.s.b.SimpleBrokerMessageHandler     : BrokerAvailabilityEvent[available=true, SimpleBrokerMessageHandler [org.springframework.messaging.simp.broker.DefaultSubscriptionRegistry@62c1be01]]
2022-08-21 20:31:29.630  INFO 10044 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.m.s.b.SimpleBrokerMessageHandler     : Started.
2022-08-21 20:31:29.635  INFO 10044 --- [  restartedMain] c.capston.chatting.ChattingApplication   : Started ChattingApplication in 2.448 seconds (JVM running for 3.017)
2022-08-21 20:31:29.637  INFO 10044 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.b.JobLauncherApplicationRunner   : Running default command line with: []
2022-08-21 20:31:30.054  INFO 10044 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [SimpleJob: [name=inactiveMemberJob3]] launched with the following parameters: [{}]
2022-08-21 20:31:30.189  INFO 10044 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Step already complete or not restartable, so no action to execute: StepExecution: id=2, version=3, name=inactiveMemberStep, status=COMPLETED, exitStatus=COMPLETED, readCount=0, filterCount=0, writeCount=0 readSkipCount=0, writeSkipCount=0, processSkipCount=0, commitCount=1, rollbackCount=0, exitDescription=
2022-08-21 20:31:30.255  INFO 10044 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [SimpleJob: [name=inactiveMemberJob3]] completed with the following parameters: [{}] and the following status: [COMPLETED] in 128ms
2022-08-21 20:31:30.634  INFO 10044 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [SimpleJob: [name=simpleJob]] launched with the following parameters: [{}]
2022-08-21 20:31:30.759  INFO 10044 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Step already complete or not restartable, so no action to execute: StepExecution: id=1, version=3, name=simpleStep1, status=COMPLETED, exitStatus=COMPLETED, readCount=0, filterCount=0, writeCount=0 readSkipCount=0, writeSkipCount=0, processSkipCount=0, commitCount=1, rollbackCount=0, exitDescription=
2022-08-21 20:31:30.824  INFO 10044 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [SimpleJob: [name=simpleJob]] completed with the following parameters: [{}] and the following status: [COMPLETED] in 125ms
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the return type doesn't work"? Do yo have an error? a compilation issue? According to the log message `Step already complete or not restartable, so no action to execute`, your step does not seem to be executed. So probably that is the reason you are not seeing your log message. Have you tried to set `allowStartIfComplete` to `true` on your step?

Comment: Thank you for the update, glad you resolved your issue! I will add an answer with those details, please consider accepting it since it helped. Thank you upfront!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the log message `Step already complete or not restartable, so no action to execute`, your step does not seem to be executed. So probably that is the reason you are not seeing your log message.

You can set `allowStartIfComplete` to `true` on your step and that should work.